# Why are entanglement breaking channels, defined as $\Phi(\rho)=\sum_a \operatorname{Tr}(\mu(a)\rho)\sigma_a$, entanglement breaking?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-operation, linear-algebra, povm, entanglement-breaking-channels

Define an *entanglement breaking channel* $\Phi$ as a channel (CPTP map) of the form
$$\Phi(\rho) = \sum_a \operatorname{Tr}(\mu(a)\rho) \sigma_a\tag A$$
for some POVM $\{\mu(a)\}_a$ and states $\sigma_a$.

It is mentioned *e.g.* in ([Horodecki, Shor, Ruskai 2003](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0302031)) that $\Phi$ is entanglement breaking *iff* it "breaks entanglement", that is, is such that
$$(\Phi\otimes I)\Gamma \quad\text{ is separable for every state } \Gamma.\tag B$$

This equivalence is proved, I think, in pages 5 and 6 of the above reference, but I can't quite follow the exposition there. In particular, the proof that (A) implies (B) seems to rely on expressing the action of $\Phi\otimes I$ on $\Gamma$ via a partial trace involving some operators $E_k$ which however are not defined (there might be a typo somewhere in the text, I'm not sure).

What are good ways to prove the equivalence between (A) and (B)?

Comment: Presumably, the E_k are the mu_a. (A)=>(B) is completely trivial. The backward direction is probably easiest via Choi-Jamiolkowski (the mu_a and sigma_a are simply the states in the separable decomposition of the Choi state).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimalist formal proof (I'll use $\mu_a\equiv \mu(a)$):

$\textrm{(A)}\Rightarrow\textrm{(B)}:$
Let $\Gamma\ge0$. Then,
$$
(\Phi_A\otimes I_B)(\Gamma_{AB}) = \sum (\sigma_a)_A\otimes\mathrm{tr}_A[((\mu_a)_A\otimes I_B)\,\Gamma_{AB}]\ ,
$$
which is a separable decomposition, since $\mathrm{tr}_A[((\mu_a)_A\otimes I_B)\,\Gamma_{AB}]\ge0$ because it describes the action of the CP map $\rho\mapsto\mathrm{tr}(\mu_a\rho)$ (measurement conditioned on outcome) on the $A$ system.

$\textrm{(B)}\Rightarrow\textrm{(A)}:$ Let $\chi_{AB}=(\Phi_A\otimes I_B)(\Omega_{AB})=\sum \tilde\sigma_a\otimes \tilde\mu_a$ be the Choi state of $\Phi$ (with $\Omega$ the maximally entangled state). Then, the map $\Phi$ can be obtained from $\chi_{AB}$ as
\begin{align*}
\Phi(\rho) &= \mathrm{tr}_B(\chi_{AB}(I\otimes\rho^T))\\
&=\sum  \mathrm{tr}_B((\tilde\sigma_a\otimes\tilde\mu_a)(I\otimes\rho^T))\\
&=\sum \tilde\sigma_A\,\mathrm{tr}(\tilde\mu_a\rho^T)\\
&=\sum \tilde\sigma_A\,\mathrm{tr}(\tilde\mu_a^T\rho)
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows from $\mathrm{tr}(X)=\mathrm{tr}(X^T)$.

Comment: Intuitively, the transpose is related to the different "direction" in which the objects act: $\Phi$ acts *on* a state, while $\tilde\mu_a$ *is* a state, so for it to *act* on a state the indices have to be flipped. (Formally, this amounts to putting $\tilde\mu_a$ and $\rho$ next to each other and projecting onto the ME state.)

Comment: Nice, this kind of formalism is acceptable (for me), while this derivation is simpler conceptually.

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed some weirdly written exposition with typos, but the result is correct.

Let $\Phi(\rho) = \sum_k R_k \text{Tr}(F_k\rho)$ and $\Phi_k(\rho)=R_k \text{Tr}(F_k\rho)$.

For $\Gamma = \rho_1 \otimes \rho_2$ we have
$$
(I \otimes \Phi_k)(\Gamma) = \rho_1 \otimes \Phi_k(\rho_2) = \rho_1 \otimes R_k\text{Tr}(F_k\rho_2) = 
$$
$$
= \rho_1\text{Tr}(F_k\rho_2) \otimes R_k = \text{Tr}_2(\rho_1\otimes F_k\rho_2) \otimes R_k =
$$
$$
= \text{Tr}_2(I\otimes F_k \cdot \Gamma) \otimes R_k = \text{Tr}_2(I\otimes \sqrt{ F_k} \cdot \Gamma \cdot I\otimes \sqrt{F_k}) \otimes R_k.
$$
By linearity, it's true for every $\Gamma$, and also by linearity we can write that
$$
(I \otimes \Phi)(\Gamma) = \sum_k \text{Tr}_2(I\otimes\sqrt{ F_k} \cdot \Gamma \cdot I\otimes\sqrt{ F_k}) \otimes R_k
$$
This proves (A) => (B) since for density matrix $\Gamma$ we have $\text{Tr}_2(I\otimes\sqrt{ F_k} \cdot \Gamma \cdot I\otimes \sqrt{ F_k}) =: \gamma_k Q_k$ where $\gamma_k>0$ and $Q_k$ is a density matrix (they also have typo in the definition of $Q_k$).

To prove (B) => (A) we take $\Gamma = |\beta\rangle\langle\beta|$, where $|\beta\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_i |i\rangle|i\rangle$ and use the separability of $(I \otimes \Phi )(\Gamma)$. That is, If
$$(I \otimes \Phi )(|\beta\rangle\langle\beta|)=\sum_n p_n |v_n\rangle\langle v_n| \otimes |w_n\rangle\langle w_n|$$
then it can be showed that
$$\Phi(\rho) = \Omega(\rho) := d\sum_n |w_n\rangle\langle w_n| \text{Tr}\big(\rho p_n \big(|v_n\rangle\langle v_n|\big)^T\big).$$
To prove $\Phi = \Omega$ it's enough to show that $(I \otimes \Phi )(|\beta\rangle\langle\beta|) = (I \otimes \Omega )(|\beta\rangle\langle\beta|)$.

This is the (C) => (A) implication of Theorem 4 in the paper (that has a minor mistake).

Comment: What's the point of taking square roots of the F_k? Also, the "To prove Phi=Omega" - isn't that just the backwards map of Choi-Jamiolkowski?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It's then easier to see why $I \otimes F_k \cdot \Gamma$ is positive semidefinite (if $\Gamma$ is), also it's aligned with the presentation from the paper.
It might be unnecessary and obvious at all from physical intuition, but I prefer to support that intuition by precise math.
The state $(I \otimes \Phi)(|\beta\rangle\langle\beta|)$ is the Choi's matrix of $\Phi$, so of course $\Phi$ is an image of the backwards map.

Comment: I agree - I just felt it is not required if one wants the shortest possible proof (different people have different primary interests ;) ): After all, it is the post-measurement state on the 1-system, so it must be positive. Regarding the 2nd point, I was just wondering why you said "To prove Phi=Omega" given it is the backwards Choi state. Or did you not want to use that? (In some sense, you *anyway* use Choi, because you use that the channel is characterized by its action on the ME state.)

Comment: You know this from physical intuition that $Q_k$ is a post-measurement state (so it must be positive), which is disentangled from the preparation $R_k$. It's good to know this explanation, but this can't be used as a rigorous proof, in my opinion (which is biased because I'm mathematician :)). 

As for 2nd point, the introduction of a new variable $\Omega$ is indeed unnecessary, but I just followed the paper here. In essence, we just need to show that the backwards image of a separable Choi matrix is a channel that has Holevo form.

Comment: If you know that the "physical intuition" is not just "intuition", but you have been proving it when learning QI (where such things *should* be proven), then it *is* a formal argument. It is only not a formal argument if you never proved it and *only* base it on physical intuition. It is like I say "it is intuitive the projection of one vector onto another unit vector is shorter than the original vector" and you tell me I cannot use Cauchy-Schwarz if I am led by intuition. Many mathematicians *are* led by intuition: It tells you which arguments to use!

Comment: (Sorry for the long comment, but I am a bit allergic to saying that arguments which are led by physical intuition are not rigorous because of that.)

Comment: I'm not against formal arguments. I think in this case the formal argument that "EBR channel $\Phi$ is an observation on the 1st system + preparation on the 2nd system" doesn't immediately explains what is the action of $(I \otimes \Phi)$ when applied to some entangled state $\Gamma$. It wasn't obvious to me (and to the author of this question, I suppose). Can you think of a similar (generalized) characterization of $(I \otimes \Phi )(\Gamma)$ when $\Phi$ is not ebr? 
Anyway, it's better to be more cautious then less cautious :)

Comment: Well, knowing the OP here and at physics for a while, I was indeed surprised by the question, so I would be interested in hearing what the difficulty was. I'd say "What is the residual state after measuring part of a system with a POVM" is a much more fundamental question than the one above. I wouldn't hesitate to ask this in my QI exam. About caution, I agree on the one hand, but I feel that if there is a simple proof one should give a simple proof. Otherwise, people will get the impression that QI is complicated business ;)  (But of course, what is complicated is in the eye of the observer.)

Comment: (BTW, a square-root-free argument for positivity would be to note that for all $P>0$, $\mathrm{tr}_1[P\,\mathrm{tr}_2 ((I\otimes F) \Gamma)] = \mathrm{tr} ((P\otimes F) \Gamma)\ge 0$, so $\mathrm{tr}_2 ((I\otimes F) \Gamma)\ge0$.

Comment: "What is the residual state after measuring part of a system with a POVM" – this is actually a good question. 
From what I observe many courses and books omit the fact that PVM $\{P_i\}$ on a subsystem corresponds to the PVM $\{I \otimes P_i\}$ on the whole system (same for POVMs). I don't think this is "obvious", it should be postulated or derived, but no one does this explicitly. Even though this fact is used everywhere in QI, it's a blind spot of newcomers, since it's used implicitly.

Comment: Even in this question the set of operators $\{E_k = I \otimes F_k\}$ is actually the derived POVM (but not the same POVM $\{F_k\}$ as I see it).

Comment: Interesting, I always felt that this was the way to *introduce* the tensor product for operators in QI. Certainly that's how I do it in my lecture: Acting with M on A means not doing anything on B, so it is M x I. If you go further and also do N on B, you get M x N. The only question is whether you motivate this by restricting what M and N are. But as I said, how else would you even *motivate* the use of tensor products when acting with anything (evolution, measurement, ...) on composite systems? It seems not including that in the course means skipping the central aspect ...

Comment: ... of composite systems, which I think explains why I cannot understand the point of the question.

Comment: Well, if you're introducing tensor products from such physics perspective then it should be natural for students to extend everything by tensoring by $I$. To me, it's a mathematical construct that I've learned before it's use in physics, $A$ and $I \otimes A$ has a different meaning in my mind. Also, it's a questionable statement that $I \otimes A$ does nothing to the first subsystem if we act on some entangled state. Surely, the reduced state doesn't change, but the entanglement changes and it involves both subsystems.

Comment: The way of introducing it is to say that if you have another *unentangled* system, it should act as I x A. Otherwise, physical experiments would be meaningless, because there would be no way to run an experiment with the world around it. The rest is linearity. In any case, when you introduce composite systems, even entirely axiomatically, you *have* to say what it means to act on part of the sytem. Otherwise, you just haven't understood anything about composite systems. (I mean, just take gates in a QC: A 2-qubit gate U acts as U x I.)

Comment: I think from your perspective the no-communication theorem is also obvious :)
I also like to use simpler arguments, but precise math gives confidence and reliability, which I value much more.

Comment: I am a bit offended by your insinuation that my argument is less rigorous than yours, just because it makes use of results you are not familiar with. A proof is not more rigorous just because it uses more elementary steps. In fact, a key point of university maths education is to teach people refined tools so they do not have to prove everything using elementary steps only. (And regarding the tensoring with Identity: This should be obvious *especially* from a math perspective: At some point I was teaching QI to mathematicians and introduced the partial trace in the "usual" technical way, ...

Comment: ... and they were very confused about what I was doing, until they realized that I just explained the "canonical embedding of the trace into the tensor product" (their words), and then everything was clear to them, *without* any need for a technical, basis-dependent formulation of the partial trace.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Let's agree that rigorousness is a subjective thing. Someone could demand that every mathematical theorem should be formalized in ZFC. But no one do this in reality. I didn't mean any offenses, sorry if it hurt your feelings. I'm out of this conversation now.

Comment: Having done the derivation now myself, I believe there is a transpose missing in the last equation (where you define Omega).

Comment: Indeed, I've missed this mistake from the paper. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That (A) implies (B) should be obvious from the physical intuition behind (A): A channel of the form (A) can be interpreted as performing a POVM measurement with elements $\mu_a$, and on obtaining outcome $a$ preparing the state $\sigma_a$. It should be obvious that this breaks any entanglement, since it (destructively) measures the input.

(Note that also proving this direction is a one-liner - the output will be $\mu_a$ times the partial trace of the input with $\mu_a$.)

Comment: I don't disagree with the result being physically intuitive, which is part of the reason why I'd expect it to be reachable with a "proportionally simple" mathematical proof, which the one given in the reference isn't, imo. But yea, if I'm deciphering your last sentence correctly, that's certainly a better way to look at it. I think you are just noting that $(\Phi\otimes I)\Gamma=\sum_a \sigma_a \otimes \mathrm{Tr}_1[(\mu(a)\otimes I)\Gamma]$, yes? This reflects the physical intuition nicely.

Comment: (which looking back at the paper is the same thing they were doing, though I was confused by their notation). For the other direction, from the other comment, you take $\Gamma$ as the maxent state, thus getting the Choi, from which you can infer the structure of the channel itself. I guess the physical observation here is that how the extension acts on maximally entangled states determines the action of the channel itself (which is probably the intuition underlying the usefulness of the Choi in general).

Comment: @glS Indeed, that's what I meant. (You just have to prove that this is positive, but since it is the residual state after applying a CP map $\mathrm{tr}(\mu(a))\,\cdot\,)$ to half the system, this is clear.) For the converse, if you know how the backwards direction of the Choi isomorphism works, namely $\mathcal E(\rho) = \mathrm{tr}_2 (\sigma(I\otimes \rho^T))$, with $\sigma$ the Choi state), it is also immediate. -- I was in fact thinking of writing a minimalist formal answer. Would that be of interest?

Comment: I think so!$\,\,\,$

Comment: Done! (And I learned something doing it!)