# Is there any simple mathematical proof that measurement destroys entanglement?

Tags: entanglement, measurement

Is there a simple mathematical way to prove that measurement destroys entanglement?

I can see that this is indeed true if I just take a specific measurement on an entangled state. What I am looking for is a mathematical proof that this is true in general.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#Mathematical_formalism) may help

Comment: Sorry, but which part says measurement destroys entanglement?

Comment: Not sure if there is a simple proof, but one approach would be to convince yourself that measurement is a certain type of quantum channel and the outputs of this type of channel cannot be entangled.

Comment: As currently stated, the claim isn't true. For example, measuring a Bell state in the Bell basis does not destroy entanglement. In fact, measurement may create entanglement as is the case when measuring a computational basis state in the Bell basis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not true in general that measurement destroys entanglement. However, if the measurement basis consists of unentangled states and if the measurement outcome unambiguously identifies a specific basis element then this is indeed the case. Also, this type of measurement performed on a subsystem destroys its entanglement with other subsystems.

### Projective measurement on a full system

Projective measurement can be described by a basis $|\psi_k\rangle$ labelled by a set of outcomes $\lambda_k$ for $k=1,\dots,d$ where $d$ is the dimension of the underlying Hilbert space. If $\lambda_k$ are all distinct, then the measurement outcome unambiguously identifies a specific basis element. In this case, the observable describing the measurement is said to be *non-degenerate*. When such a measurement is performed on the state $|\phi\rangle$ then the outcome $\lambda_k$ occurs with the probability $|\langle\phi|\psi_k\rangle|^2$ and the post-measurement state is $|\psi_k\rangle$.

If the measurement is non-degenerate, then the post-measurement state is *one of the elements of the basis* describing the measurement. Consequently, such measurement destroys entanglement if and only if the basis state $|\psi_k\rangle$ corresponding to the observed outcome $\lambda_k$ is unentangled. In particular, non-degenerate measurement is guaranteed to destroy entanglement if all the basis states $|\psi_k\rangle$ are unentangled.

On the other hand, if the measured observable is degenerate, then the post-measurement state may preserve preexisting entanglement.

### Projective measurement on a subsystem

Even though the subsystems $A$ and $B$ of a composite system $AB$ in a pure state $|\psi_{AB}\rangle$ may be entangled with each other, the system $AB$ in a pure state is never entangled with a third system $C$. If the measurement is non-degenerate then, by arguments above, the post-measurement state is a pure state. Therefore, the non-degenerate measurement destroys entanglement of a system being measured with other systems. If the measurement is degenerate then it may preserve entanglement between the measured system and other systems.

In summary, measurement may destroy, preserve or create entanglement between subsystems that are jointly measured. If the measurement is non-degenerate then it destroys entanglement of the system with other systems not included in the measurement.

### Example

Suppose that three subsystems $ABC$ are in a state where $A$ is not entangled with the other subsystems and $B$ and $C$ are entangled with each other, e.g. $|0_A\rangle\otimes(|0_B0_C\rangle+|1_B1_C\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. If we measure the subsystems $AB$ in the Bell basis, then we create entanglement between $A$ and $B$ and destroy the entanglement between $B$ and $C$. Indeed, the post-measurement state of $AB$ is a Bell state and the post-measurement state of $C$ is a computational basis state.

---

<sup>$^1$ Measurement consisting of rank-1 projectors. Equivalently, measurement of an observable corresponding to a Hermitian operator with non-degenerate spectrum.</sup>

Comment: That makes sense thanks !!

Comment: One extra question though, can you give an example of basis states which are entangled or rather, a measurement where after measurement, the entangled state remains entangled?

Comment: A good example is the [Bell basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state). Measurement in this basis will create (or preserve) entanglement since all states in the basis are (maximally) entangled.

Comment: So basically if you measure in a bell basis the resulting states would be one of the basis and since this basis itself is entangled the resulting state would be entangled. 
Thanks a tonne :)

Comment: Exactly! You're welcome :-)

Comment: I have another question sorry, if we have an entangled state and we perform measurement on both the qubits. If the first qubit measurement makes its post measurement state as $|\psi_k>$ and second qubit's measurement makes its post measurement state as $|\lambda_j>$. The resultant state would be $|\psi_k> \otimes |\lambda_j>$ correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. This last comment suggests that @gIS's interpretation of your question is correct, i.e. you're asking about a measurement on a subsystem of a composite system. I have expanded my answer to account for both cases ("full system" and "subsystem" measurement) and added an example that demonstrates how to account for them in a single situation. Hope this helps!

Comment: You said "Moreover, by arguments above, the post-measurement state is a pure state.". So lets just assume a 2 qubit system which is entangled. If I perform measurement $M_1 \otimes M_2$, then because the resultant states of each qubit is a pure state, the resultant state of the system is always non entangled. Is this a correct statement?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct overall, but there is a caveat related to the form of the observable $M_1\otimes M_2$. If you imagine two independent measurements, one on each qubit, then yes the statement is correct. In this case, independence rules out entangling measurements such as the measurement in the Bell basis. If $M_1\otimes M_2$ has non-degenerate spectrum (i.e. all eigenvalues are distinct) then the statement is also correct.

Comment: However, there are observables (necessarily with degenerate spectrum) that take the product form $M_1\otimes M_2$ but preserve entanglement! For example, the joint observable $Z\otimes Z$ preserves the entanglement of the Bell states, but measuring $Z$ on the first and second qubit independently breaks the entanglement. The difference between the two scenarios is related to the fact that measuring $Z$ on each qubit separately gives you more information (2 bits) than measuring the joint observable $Z\otimes Z$ (1 bit). This fact is useful in quantum error correction.

Comment: Hmm. I understood the first comment. But am having a hard time understanding the 2nd comment or rather understanding why that is the case. Why is it the $Z \otimes Z$ joint observable different from measuring $Z$ on each qubit separately? Wouldn't the latter case also be represented as $Z \otimes Z$?

Comment: Consider the possible outcomes in each case. Measuring $Z$ on the first qubit tells you whether it was $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$. Similarly for the second qubit. Overall, you get to distinguish the four different cases (hence 2 bits of information): $|00\rangle$, $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$. On the other hand, $Z\otimes Z$ only lets you distinguish between $\mathrm{span}(|00\rangle, |11\rangle)$ (eigenspace of the $+1$ eigenvalue) and $\mathrm{span}(|01\rangle, |10\rangle)$ (eigenspace of the $-1$ eigenvalue) (hence just 1 bit of information).

Comment: Ok that makes sense. 
Is there a condition where measurement $M_1 \otimes M_2$ preserves entanglement like the case with $Z  \otimes Z$ Or is it a trial and error type of thing?

Comment: Yes, there are probably many conditions one could formulate. For example, this will be the case when $M_1\otimes M_2$ has an entangled eigenstate. In this case, $M_1\otimes M_2$ preserves the entanglement in this state. Moreover, $M_1\otimes M_2$ has at least one other entangled eigenstate with the same eigenvalue (exercise for the reader) and consequently is unable distinguish between the states.

Comment: That makes sense.
Thanks a tonne by the way for helping me out so much :).

Comment: Your subsystem measurements destroy entanglement is not correct. I think you've implicitly assumed rank 1 projectors. If you allow larger rank projectors then it is not true anymore. E.g., larger rank projectors in the Schmidt basis will not necessarily destroy entanglement.

Comment: @Rammus You're right of course. Corrected. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The question is not completely well-defined as stated, because the answer depends on what precisely you mean with "measurement", and what you assume the post-measurement states to be.

A possible interpretation is: consider a bipartite state $\rho$, and suppose some kind of measurement is performed on one part of it (and leaving the other untouched). The most general way to describe the process of performing some measurement, after which the state becomes something else conditionally to the measurement outcome, is via an *entanglement breaking channel*. For a proof that these always destroy entanglement, see [this post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16565/55).